# Installshield Warning -7205: what does it mean

Tags: module, merge, windows-installer, installshield

I get while running my installshield setup. The official installshield guide doesn't say what this error is. My output logs for the build states:

ISDEV : warning -7205: Skipping file crdb_ado.dll.AEDB3316_9515_4FC0_AB37_ED59C4AFBEA8 due to unmerged or missing component crdb_ado.dll.AEDB3316_9515_4FC0_AB37_ED59C4AFBEA8 in merge module

But this doesn't help me resolve the problem.
could anyone kindly explain?

Comment: It looks like it might be a merge module dependency issue. Merge modules can be marked to be dependent on other merge modules, and the message may mean it won't merge a merge module because it can't find a dependent MM.

Comment: Thats what I thought it looked like but I don't have any merge modules / redistributables included within my package. Because of this im thinking its more to to with a 'missing component'. But how on earth does a component go missing?

Comment: EDIT: Having gone and checked the report for my build it does in fact have 2 merge modules. But how can I check where they are? I only have components and features as far as I am aware?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not that familiar with IS that I know where the merge modules are viewable in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same warnings. In my case, it was due to the fact that, by default, InstallShield [limits the number of files](http://flexerasoftware.force.com/articles/en_US/INFO/Q105881) in an install to 32,767.

This is the resolution from the [article](http://flexerasoftware.force.com/articles/en_US/INFO/Q105881)...

> The maximum number of files that can be included in an MSI-based project is dependent upon the number of bits available in the Media table. The number of bits in the Media table is 15. By default, a maximum of 32,767 files can be added directly to a project. However, larger packages can be authored.
>   To author a larger package, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Backup the following file: <EditorProductPath>\Support\0409\IsMsiPkg.itp.
>      Note: By default, <EditorProduct Path> is the installed location of the MSI Editor (DevStudio, IS X, etc)
> 2. Overwrite this file by renaming the file: <Product Path>Support\0409\IsMsiPkgLarge.itp to IsMsiPkg.itp
> 3. Rebuild the project.
>
> This uses the larger InstallShield template that allows more than 32,767 files to be included in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [link](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield18helplib/MMBuildLocation.htm) to documentation where described how to change path to MergeModule files location.
Don't 100% sure, but could you please check the path where your project **builds**, perhaps it has very long name (>255 chars with MergeModules file names). It also might be a problem.